# ARC Welder stays on loading forever after choosing APK

Tags: android, linux, macos, google-chrome-arc

I am using a Intel Core i5 64-bit MacBook Pro with 64-bit Chrome (version 55), but ARC Welder doesn't work on Mac OS X Sierra for me... After I choose an APK, it just stays on loading forever, and never finishes. I have tried many different APKs, and they all don't work. However, when I ran Linux (using Parallels) and tried ARC Welder, it worked.

I don't want to have to open Linux every time I want to use the app though. Thanks for your help in advance!

Edit: I have now been able to pass the loading screen, however now when I click "Test", it starts loading for a while, then nothing happens.

Comment: how did you manage to pass the loading screen?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?